# Equation for multiple peak surface to test particle swarm optimising algorithm

Tags: surfaces

i have developed a particle swarm optimisation algorithm that i am running some tests on.

It is able to solve simple equations like this:

$x^2 + y^2 + 300y - 254x + 3$

with only one optimum

but when i apply it to my real-world problem, i think it is getting stuck at local optima and i would like to be able to run some controlled tests on a surface with a couple of optima at different places to see how it behaves because i dont know the shape of my real-world problem space.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any simple equations for generating such surfaces, something similar to this would be perfect:

[image: surface]
<sub>(source: [originlab.com](http://www.originlab.com/www/products/images/multiple_peak_fit_to_surface_data_600.png))</sub>

it doesnt have to be exactly that (i just googled an image of a multi-optima surface in case i didnt describe myself properly), just a surface with a few optima that i can test my algorithm on.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I managed to find a great site with a whole heap of useful functions for testing global optimisation algorithms, along with matlab and R implementations.

http://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/optimization.html

very useful indeed!